# How can i try to get json string when i receive something more that json string?

Tags: javascript, json

Good morning, folks.

I have a php using AJAX. For some updates been emplemented currently i'm using json, but sometimes we receive something like

```
'<div class="trigger error">Some error</div>{"1":{"message":"Success something."},"2":{"message":"There is update available"}}'
```

There is a way to write something like

```
try{
   obj = JSON.parse(data);
   function_to_print_result(obj);
} catch (e){
   var string_json = REGEX(something(data));
   var old_system_error = REGEX(something(data));

   try{
      obj = JSON.parse(string_json);

      function_to_print_result(obj);
      function_to_print_old_error(old_system_error);
   } catch (e){
      $('.msg').empty().html(data);
   }
}
```

I'm trying understand REGEX but, realy, i have so much difficult. I need only REGEX.

Very thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you really need to work on fixing the API response. There is no way valid JSON would accept HTML strings in it.

Now, try this temporary solution to extract the data and error message from the mixed value of the API response.

```js
var data = '<div class="trigger error">Some error</div>{"1":{"message":"Success something."},"2":{"message":"There is update available"}}';
var obj;
try{
   obj = JSON.parse(data);
   function_to_print_result(obj);
} catch (e){
   var old_system_error;
   var regex = /^<[a-zA-Z"= ]+>[a-zA-Z ]+<\/+[a-zA-Z]+>(?={)/gi;
   var string_json = data.replace(regex, function(match, token){
    old_system_error = match;
    return '';
   })

   try{
      obj = JSON.parse(string_json);
      console.log(obj);
      console.log(old_system_error);
   } catch (e){
      console.log(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr @HeriHeheSetiawan. I will work to understand regex functions, it's a difficult I need to overcome. Next months I want to upgrade system to use only json response.
Have a nice week.